# openapi generator, security schemas not shows the authentication button in swagger

Tags: yaml, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm using openapi generator to generate my api in java from yml file.

I'm trying to enable the security in my server, so I included:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
    type: http
    scheme: bearer
    bearerFormat: JWT
security:
 - bearerAuth: []
```

but with this, I can not see anything related with security in my api file.

I tried to include this in the controller file that if I'm not wrong it is the same and it works:

```
@SecurityScheme(type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP, scheme = "bearer", name = "Authorization", bearerFormat = "JWT")
```

can it be I'm missing something in the yml file in order it to work?